# How can I convert JS to TS?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I read many articles about TypeScript and couldn't find anything. What type to set for elements X and Y? or how to convert the code to TS? thanks in advance for your help

```
const x = document.getElementById("password-input");
const y = document.getElementById("img");
function showPass() {
            if (x.type === "password") {
            x.type = "text";
            y.src = "png"

        } else {
            x.type = "password";
            y.src = "png"
        }
    }
```

Comment: typescript will infer types. there's no need to declare it explicitly. there's also the `HtmlImageElement` and `HtmlInputElement`...

Comment: TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, so any JavaScript snippet is also valid for TypeScript. You can add type annotations and many other cool things

Answer (score 0):

With the `!` sign you said that this element won't be null (if you are sure that element is in your HTML document), and `as HTMLInputElemnt` is for indicating your element type.

To read more about it, you can read [this article](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/dom-manipulation.html).

```
const x = document.getElementById("password-input")! as HTMLInputElement;
const y = document.getElementById("img")! as HTMLInputElement;

function showPass() {
            if (x.type === "password") {
            x.type = "text";
            y.src = "png"

        } else {
            x.type = "password";
            y.src = "png"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't just use TS in the browser, you'll need to compile it. For your specific use case, you will need to tell TS what the `HTMLElement` is for x and y, otherwise it won't like `x.type` and `y.src` as `src` and `type` aren't properties on `HTMLElement`

```
const x: HTMLInputElement = document.getElementById("password-input");
const y: HTMLImageElement = document.getElementById("img");
function showPass() {
            if (x.type === "password") {
            x.type = "text";
            y.src = "png"

        } else {
            x.type = "password";
            y.src = "png"
        }
    }
```